# Gauge fractions with exponents - No Calculator

Tags: intuition

How does one (without the use of Calculator) determine that $5/6$ is less than $(35/36)^6$? How is this done mentally?

Comment: Bernoulli inequality, $(1+x)^n \geqslant 1 + nx$ for $x \geqslant -1$.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at your second number, it can be written as

$$( 1  -  \frac{1}{36} )^6 \ = \ 1 \ - \ 6 \cdot  1^5 \cdot \frac{1}{36} \ + \ \binom 62 \cdot 1^4 \cdot (\frac{1}{36})^2 \ - \ ...  $$

with the remaining (unwritten) terms being *very* small (the first two terms *equal* $ \ \frac{5}{6} \ $ ) .  So $ \ \frac{5}{6} \ $ ends up being slightly smaller than $ ( 1  -  \frac{1}{36} )^6 \ $ (by a little less than $ \ 15  \cdot \frac{1}{36^2} \ = \ \frac{5}{432} \ \approx  \ 0.0116 \ $ ) .

[This is what **Daniel Fischer** is briefly describing.]